# Why did I get $1200 stimulus check? Was a resident alien for tax but moved out of US in Nov 2019

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, non-resident, covid-19

I was a student on a visa in the US and was also working at the university from 2012 to Nov 2019. I then moved out of the US at the end of Nov 2019. Officially, I'm still a student at my US university until May 2020 when I get my degree, but I'm no longer paying tuition or getting paid for my job. I noticed I received the stimulus check of $1200 in my US bank account that I hadn't closed. Am I really eligible for this even though I'm not in US? I'll be filing 2019 taxes though.

Comment: If you were F-1 or J-1 student in the US no more than 5 years, you SHOULD NOT have filed as resident, unless you were married to a citizen or resident on a joint return. If you did incorrectly file as resident for 2018 _or_ 2019, and IRS didn't catch it which they wouldn't this quickly, and you were under the $75k (or $150k) AGI limit and not a dependent of another taxpayer, that's why they think you're eligible. See https://money.stackexchange.com/q/123281/ https://money.stackexchange.com/q/41438/ https://money.stackexchange.com/q/60709/ https://money.stackexchange.com/q/46188/

Comment: I was on f1 student visa in the US for more more than 5 years so I correctly filed as resident for tax purposes. I have edited the question to include this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IRS used 2019 tax-filing information where available (otherwise 2018) to determine eligibility for stimulus checks. Since you were a legal resident of the U.S. in 2019 and filed your taxes as such, you were deemed eligible. The way the law is written, the checks are basically an advance on a 2020 tax credit; however, if you would otherwise be deemed ineligible based on your 2020 tax/residency status, you do not have to pay back what you received. You are not required to file taxes if you wouldn't otherwise, and if you *do* file U.S. taxes, the amount you received will not be clawed back. So the money is yours!